# Hide error: The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later

Tags: drupal, entity, feed

I got this message all time in the bottom left of my browser, even the site is full working. It is a bit annoying for user. I have tried to hide it using css but seems impossible.

[image]

Do you guys know how to hide the error message? This is the error from the logs file:

```
Error: Call to a member function getPlugins() on null in Drupal\feeds\Entity\Feed->preSave() (line 443 of /var/www/html/modules/contrib/feeds/src/Entity/Feed.php) 
#0 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php(434): Drupal\feeds\Entity\Feed->preSave(Object(Drupal\feeds\FeedStorage)) 
#1 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityStorageBase.php(298): Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->doPreSave(Object(Drupal\feeds\Entity\Feed)) 
#2 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php(389): Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase->doPreSave(Object(Drupal\feeds\Entity\Feed)) 
#3 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php(761): Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->save(Object(Drupal\feeds\Entity\Feed)) 
#4 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Entity.php(364): Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save(Object(Drupal\feeds\Entity\Feed)) 
#5 /var/www/html/modules/contrib/feeds/feeds.module(46): Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity->save() 
#6 [internal function]: feeds_cron() 
#7 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ModuleHandler.php(391): call_user_func_array('feeds_cron', Array) 
#8 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Cron.php(223): Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->invoke('feeds', 'cron') 
#9 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Cron.php(122): Drupal\Core\Cron->invokeCronHandlers() 
#10 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/ProxyClass/Cron.php(75): Drupal\Core\Cron->run() 
#11 /var/www/html/core/modules/automated_cron/src/EventSubscriber/AutomatedCron.php(65): Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Cron->run() 
#12 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Component/EventDispatcher/ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php(111): Drupal\automated_cron\EventSubscriber\AutomatedCron->onTerminate(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\PostResponseEvent), 'kernel.terminat...', Object(Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher)) 
#13 /var/www/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(84): Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.terminat...', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\PostResponseEvent)) 
#14 /var/www/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(32): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->terminate(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), Object(Drupal\Core\Render\HtmlResponse)) 
#15 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(634): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->terminate(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), Object(Drupal\Core\Render\HtmlResponse)) 
#16 /var/www/html/index.php(22): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->terminate(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), Object(Drupal\Core\Render\HtmlResponse)) 
#17 {main}.
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be general error and to fix it you should try to debug/trace the issue from the code. What I got from your question is you want to remove this error and make it now appearing for the users, if this is on production environment you should disable error reporting to the front-end, this can be done in D8 by going to admin/config/development/logging and select "Error messages to display" and save your configuration. after that you can debug and trace this error.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: It seems the problem from the Feeds module, but there is no fixing patch yet. I have set the "Error messages to display" to none already, but the error still appears.